# wake from sleep using mouse

Tags: usb, wakeup

I am trying to get my wired usb mouse and keyboard to wake my intel 3g pos ubuntu 16.04 desktop computer. It wakes with the power button.  I had 14.04 on it till about 5 days ago.  I did a clean install with 16.04.  It would wake up in 14.04 with a wired mouse.  I would love to have a wireless wakeup but wired is ok.  I want to keep the tower under my table.  I still concider myself a sortanewbe.  This is my first ever posted question.

I'll check back when I can.  I googled this problem quite a bit.  Cant figure out where to start.  I set the time in dconf-editor.

I did this.

```
:~$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
P0P1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
P0P3      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0
BNIC      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:02.0
P0P4      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
P0P5      S4    *disabled
P0P6      S4    *disabled
P0P7      S4    *disabled
PS2K      S3    *disabled
PS2M      S3    *disabled
USB1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
USB2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.1
USB3      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.2
USB4      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.3
EUSB      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.7
MC97      S3    *disabled
SLPB      S4    *disabled
:~$ 

:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 083a:4505 Accton Technology Corp. SMCWUSB-G 802.11bg
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05dc:c75c Lexar Media, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 040b:2011 Weltrend Semiconductor 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b38:0010 Gear Head 107-Key Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
:~$
```